# Как сделать видео фон, чтобы кадр сохранялся после перезагрузки

Tags: javascript, css, ajax, css3

Возможно ли сделать видео фон сайта так, чтобы после перезагрузки страницы или переходе на другую страницу сайта видео начиналось с того места, на котором было прервано?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно с помощью cookie.
Запоминаем:

```
document.cookie = "time=" + videoElem.currentTime;
```

Читаем:

```
var lastTime = document.cookie.split('=')[1];
```

Пишем:

```
videoElem.currentTime = lastTime;
```